# onCreateContextMenu() for EditText doesn't work on real device

Tags: android, android-edittext, contextmenu, android-compatibility

Just tried to test my app on real device (HTC Desire Z with Android 2.2). And found that my context menus doesn't work at all on `EditText`s. Otherwise context menus works: in `ListView`, `ImageView` and so on. On emulator everything works fine...

When I tap on EditText it shows something like zoom frame and then shows unusual (not standard Android alike) context menu which reads: "select text", "select all". It doesn't show my menus. 
Here are screenshots:

1. [Before tap](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B64TN1V7krz9NWQ5MzRiNjAtMWMxYS00MmU4LWJmNzYtNzRkODE3MTVhOTc0&hl=en)
2. [During tap](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B64TN1V7krz9ZThiNjA0NjctN2Y5MC00NTljLWFhMjQtYThmZmI5ZmViYWJi&hl=en)
3. [After tap](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B64TN1V7krz9MTU3MmZkODItMTdkZi00ZTJkLWI1MzQtM2Q3NjY2NTU2NDM4&hl=en) (just ordinary select text, select all, paste)

but no my menu like in emulator - [look here](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B64TN1V7krz9NGVjZWQ3ZmMtNWJhMi00NTgzLWEyMjQtNWExOGJlZTMzZmIz&hl=en)

Here's source code of my activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final String TAG=MyActivity.class.getName();

    EditText editText;
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        editText=(EditText )findViewById(R.id.editText);
        this.registerForContextMenu(editText);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Creating context menu for view="+view);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+1, Menu.NONE, "Test menu");
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Context item selected as="+item.toString());
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I have thoroughly debugged/logged everything around my code, but still Activity.onCreateContextMenu() not even called (though it's registered in proper way).

Please help - what it can be? Does it related to HTC peculiarities?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the context menu?

Comment: I'm also curious to see a screenshot of what you're seeing. I have an original Desire and I've just tried this with my phone and I correctly get my own context menu with header icon/title and my choices when I long press my EditText.

Comment: As soon as I will have access to USB debug enabled PC I will take screenshots. I suppose it will happen today evening (of Moscow/Russia time)

Comment: Look there - I have placed screenshots + supplied source

Comment: (re mod-flag; that isn't a moderation request - feel free to contact the HTC team via their normal fault-report channels, though)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I think what you are seeing there is an HTC menu.

The graphical edit context menu you are seeing is, I believe, new to more recent Desire models (Desire HD and Desire Z). What I see (with your code) on my original Desire is a popup text-based menu with the HeaderTitle set as 'Edit text' and a list such as 'Select all', 'Copy', 'Paste' etc. BUT, I do also see an entry saying 'Test menu'.

It occurs to me that when onCreateContextMenu() is called for things like ListView and ImageView, the 'menu' object passed in to that call isn't pre-populated by default. In the case off an EditText, however, it is designed to interact with the Clipboard and as such the system is providing a pre-populated menu based on the EditText's content state (e.g., if text is selected, provide a 'Copy' option; if there's text on the Clipboard provide a 'Paste' option; ...and so on).

I was able to get a Context menu without the 'edit' options by clearing the header and contents by modifying your code...

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    Log.v(TAG, "Creating context menu for view="+view);

    // Clear current contents
    menu.clearHeader();
    menu.clear();

    menu.setHeaderTitle("TEST MENU");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+1, Menu.NONE, "Test menu");
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
}
```

The fact you're getting a graphical menu (possibly derived from ContextMenu) suggests the above technique won't work so the only way around it would be to instantiate your own ContextMenu object rather than use the one passed in to onCreateContextMenu().

> I have thoroughly debugged/logged everything around my code, but still Activity.onCreateContextMenu() not even called

This seems very odd - obviously it's being called for me as I've been able to play around with the ContextMenu that is being passed to it.

**EDIT 1:** Re-thinking this, you mention that you 'tap' the EditText - is that what you are actually doing (a short touch down then finger up)?

To get my ContextMenu I have to use a 'long' press/click (touch and hold for about 1 second). When I simply tap/touch my EditText the 'soft' keyboard appears or, if the keyboard is already visible, the cursor is simply moved to a different position in the EditText box.

Obviously the Desire Z has a physical keyboard and that may cause slightly different behaviour (as well as the Desire Z having a different version of the Sense UI to my Desire).

The fact that onCreateContextMenu() is never called for you can mean only one thing and that is, what you are seeing is NOT a ContextMenu and is some other type of popup UI element. At least that is the only logical way I can understand it.

Can you confirm that a 'long' press still doesn't create a ContextMenu for you or have you been using a long press all along?

If you have tried a long press then try modifying the code as follows...

1. Implement OnClickListener

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity
       implements OnLongClickListener {
   ```
2. Set the listener for editText in onCreate...

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       editText=(EditText )findViewById(R.id.editText);
       this.registerForContextMenu(editText);
       editText.setOnLongClickListener(this); // <-- ADD THIS
   }
   ```
3. Add the listener code...

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
       android.util.Log.v(TAG, "onLongClick() called");
       if (arg0 == editText)
       {
           android.util.Log.v(TAG, "arg0 == editText");
               Toast.makeText(this, "onLongClick intercepted", 2000).show();
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           android.util.Log.v(TAG, "arg0 != editText");
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```

By doing this, I'm able to intercept the long press and, by returning 'true' from onLongClick() I'm indicating to the system that I've 'consumed' the event and it doesn't get passed on to cause the creation of my ContextMenu.

If this doesn't work for you and a short tap still causes that popup to appear, then try implementing OnClickListener and overriding onClick() instead.

The object of the exercise is that if you can intercept whatever is causing the creation of the popup you're seeing, you can then manually create and show your own ContextMenu.

Comment: No it doesn't call onCreateContextMenu() - I have double checked everything. Please help! Any ideas?

Comment: @barmaley: See my answer towards the end where I start EDIT 1:

Comment: Strange things happens... I mean as soon as I intercept long click and consume it - nothing called - neither onCreateContextMenu nor HTC menu. When I intercept and don't consume long click (return false) - I see onCreateContextMenu and no HTC menu. Can you confirm on your HTC Desire how it works with intercepted long click (returning true and false)?

Comment: I mean intercepting of long click fixes described bug, but it's unusual. It shouldn't be happen...

Comment: @barmaley: If I return 'false' from onClick() then onCreateContextMenu() is called but if I return 'true' it is not and I don't see my ContextMenu which is exactly what I'd expect. You are right - if simply listening for a long press is preventing the HTC menu even if you return false then something is not right. Have you tried this with the physical keyboard being open and also with it closed? I might expect slightly different behaviour in each case.

Comment: No it doesn't matter. Presense or absense of physical doesn't affect appearance of ContextMenu. MisterSquonk - in the end do you agree that it's platform bug? If so what I expected to do with this bug?

Comment: @barmaley: Sorry, I only just spotted your last comment. I'm not sure if it is a platform bug but what you describe certainly isn't the behaviour I'd expect. You could try reporting it to HTC but I've read a few comments that suggest getting feedback to device manufacturers can often be tricky.

Comment: @CommonsWare: WRT your answer here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972919/where-should-incompatibilities-with-different-android-devices-be-reported would you agree this appears to be a bug in the Desire Z and perhaps be able to advise barmaley as to how to report it if it is?

Comment: @MisterSquonk: @barmaley: My apologies -- I missed this comment while traveling. What we need now is a sample project that demonstrates the problem, matching the screenshots of the problem from the Desire Z. If @barmaley can supply that, I can probably take it from there to try to get this verified.

Answer (score -1):

It's the standard cut/copy/paste menu you're seeing.

See this topic for more details:

[How can I write my own context menu for copy & paste?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226836/how-can-i-write-my-own-context-menu-for-copy-paste)

Regards
HJW