# How to create context menu on double click?

Tags: android, contextmenu, double-click, tap

I need to create context menu on double click as well as on long tapping. How it can be done?

I mean normally `onCreateContextMenu` called when user press long tap on widget. In my case I need to do the same when user double clicks on widget.

**ADDED**

I know that it's not really nice option, since it's not normal for Android UI. But my primary problem is to solve UI bugs for devices of some vendors - namely HTC ([look this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402820/oncreatecontextmenu-for-edittext-doesnt-work-on-real-device)). I have seemingly resolved described issue, but still I do have problems with context menus. So as a last resort I just thought to avoid tapping through double click. Thanx for understanding...

Comment: "I need to create context menu on double click as well as on long tapping." -- why? This is not standard UX on Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare - look above, I added some comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather, you have context-sensitive actions you want tied to an `EditText`, and HTC's changes to Android are interfering with that.

First, I would reconsider using context menus in general, as they are not particularly discoverable, so most of your users will never find them.

Second, in the case of the `EditText`, the odds of users discovering that a double-tap will bring up a context menu will be on par with the odds that the Earth will have an extinction-level asteroid strike today.

:: looks up in sky ::

Rather than a double-tap, one option would be to put a small `ImageButton` adjacent to the `EditText`, with a downward-facing arrowhead (akin to a `Spinner`), and tie that `ImageButton` to a `PopupMenu` (ideal, but only API Level 11), a `PopupWindow`, or an `AlertDialog`. Or, in a pinch, have the `ImageButton` display a context menu when clicked via `showContextMenu()`. This too is non-standard UX, but it is at least more discoverable, as users will be used to things popping up when pressing down-arrow buttons, from both Android and other OSes.

If you are absolutely convinced that you need a double-tap, AFAIK that is not a recognized touch event, so you will need to handle the low-level touch events yourself, determine when a double-tap occurs, and do so in a way that does not interfere with the usage of the `EditText` (e.g., setting cursor position).