# Open menu on clicking the edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

My requirement is to open a menu when edittext is clicked with options "bold", "italic", "Underline", "Fonts" and "Colors".

Please can someone help me on this..

Comment: read about context menu.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402820/oncreatecontextmenu-for-edittext-doesnt-work-on-real-device

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I ended up solving this:

```
    EditText menuEdit = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.menuImageView);
    menuEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            activity.openOptionsMenu(); //This is the key method!
        }
    });
```

---

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;    
}
```

---

```
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.demographics:

            return true;
        case R.id.settings:
            Log.v("v", "settings clicked");
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
     }
}
```